# More information on transformation warning

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, datum

Software: ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5

Issue: datum transformation error

Want: some details on where the error can be found

Detail: like most folks at some point, I am getting a "transformation warning" error within a Pro project as it loads (and I believe it also throws the error as the project does its occasional backup). Sometimes I have many maps and layouts open (with various other maps referenced).

Is there any way in ArcGIS Pro to get some explanation on what map/layout the warning is coming from?

I could go through each and every map but it would be beneficial to get some software feedback. Especially when I often share project files with other team members.

Comment: We're plan to rework those in a later release. Anyway, what's the exact text? Look at the map's transformation dialog to see if any layers are using a coordinate system that doesn't match the map's and don't have a transformation set.

Comment: @mkennedy That sounds like a great idea. When you refer to transformation dialog, do you mean the transformation information in Map properties? I was looking for more like information at Project level, for all maps/layouts contained within so it would be easier to locate issues. Thanks!